# Jquery Position not honoring on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make my autocomplete menu open above the input box if there is not enough space below the input box to display the menu. The code works fine except for on the initial render.
This means that it always displays at the bottom when:
1. Start searching
2. Click in the field and fire the search for the existing text in field

I have it output the `position.my` and `position.at` contents and they both are correct for "above" placement but it still displays below the input box.

I have the function called resize that is binded to window scroll and resize also. The moment you scroll the page, the menu gets positioned correctly. My suspect is that it is positioning before fully rendering.

**Code**

*_renderMenu function hook*

```
// Autocomplete _renderMenu function
$(autocomplete_object)._renderMenu = function( ul, item ) {
      var that = this;
      jQuery.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      });

      // Make sure the menu is now shown to calculate heights and etc (menu is now rendered, position rendering next)
      jQuery(ul).show();

      autocomplete.resize(ul, options);
      autocomplete.create_dropdown_handlers(ul, options);
}
```

*Resize Function*

```
// Resize function
function resize( ul, options ) {
  var height;

  // If the height of the results is smaller than the space available, set the height to the results height
  var ul_height = 0;
  jQuery(ul).find('li').each(function(i, element){
      ul_height += jQuery(element).height();
  });


  // Make the height the full height available below the input box but above the window cut off
  // Move the dropdown above the input box if there is not enough room below the input box
  var $parent = jQuery("#" + options.name);
  var padding = 25; // arbitrary number to prevent dropdown from hitting the window border in either direction
  var bottom_distance = autocomplete.getViewportHeight() - ($parent.offset().top + $parent.height()) - padding;

  var bottom_limit = 200;

  var ul_position = { 
                      my: "left top",
                      at : "left bottom",
                      of: $parent,
                      collision: 'none' 
                    };

  height = bottom_distance;

  if (bottom_distance < bottom_limit) {
    var top_distance = $parent.offset().top - padding;
    height = top_distance;
    // ----- It is getting here fine! -----
    ul_position.my = "left bottom";
    ul_position.at = "left top";
  }


  // We have room to show the entire dropdown results without a scrollbar
  if (ul_height < height) {
    height = 'auto';
  }

  // Position below or above parent depending on space
  jQuery(ul).position(ul_position);

  jQuery(ul).css({height: height == 'auto' ? height : height + 'px'});
 }
```

**TLDR:**

Jquery position is set to show above input field, but it still shows below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to update the autocomplete object's position value as well as the ul position. I believe the issue was that the initial render would inherit the autocomplete's position variable (Which defaults to showing below the input box).

Here is the new line:

```
// In the resize function after jQuery(ul).position(ul_position);
$parent.autocomplete("option", "position", ul_position); // Now the rendering is correct!
```

*Resize function addition*

```
function resize (ul, options) {
    ... 
    calculate the height and position requirements
    ...

    jQuery(ul).position(ul_position);
    $parent.autocomplete("option", "position", ul_position); // <-- Addition to honor position for rendering

}
```